# How to provide the URL which will enable players to delete their data (Playfab at backend) as per the new Data Safety form in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play, playfab

Hi as per the latest data safety form in Google Play Console , it wants me to add a link so that users can use to request that their account and associated data is deleted in playfab. In my game I collect a user's email-id, username and password only for the purpose of multiplayer game as such. But now google is asking me to add the link so that these details can be deleted . How do I do that?

Also how can I make sure that the user himself and not someone else is responsible for the deletion of the data? This can be made possible if there is some confirmation email can be sent to the user's mail box, but how do I do that?

I searched everywhere but I got [this answer](https://community.playfab.com/questions/57330/how-should-i-fill-the-new-data-safety-form-in-goog.html) but it doesn't talk about the user deleting the data so I am asking here

You can see the screenshot of the questions in the google play console here:

[image: Google Play console latest data safety form]

I asked the same question [here in Playfab forum](https://community.playfab.com/questions/141882/how-to-provide-the-url-which-will-enable-players-t.html), but my question has been put in moderation for the past 4 days. I contacted the system administrator but there is no reply from there also. If anyone here can help me that will be great

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misinterpreting the instructions. I don't think that their expectation is for the linked page to be used to request account deletion, but that it prominently feature the steps required to request account deletion.

For example, let's say you place a "delete my account" option in a menu within your game. My read is that you are required to have an 'explainer' web page that a user could follow to find and use that feature.

As to verifying user user credentials before deleting data, the [PlayFab GDPR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/playerdata/playfab-gdpr-deleting-and-exporting-player-data#deleting-a-master-player-account) says this:

> It is your responsibility as the game developer to verify that the credentials match the player requesting an export or deletion of their player data. PlayFab does *not* provide any type of verification when using these APIs.
>
> However PlayFab *does* offer an [email verification feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/engagement/emails/using-a-rule-to-verify-a-contact-email-address). But our solution isn't the only option for verification. You can create your *own* process too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if u see the OP , in the screenshot it clearly says that u have to add a link for user to request to delete their data. This link will be visible in the play console so that user can click on that. How to do that? Say if ur giving a google form so that user can enter his/her details , so should I manually go through a process after collecting them to delete their data?Will it not be tedious if have a lot of users requesting at the same time ?

Comment: On [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/qiik85/stuck_at_this_question_do_you_provide_a_way_for/) some devs basically say the same thing I did. As to the tedious issue: we can't know how many users will want you to delete their data. If you think it will be tedious, automate it.  Also, I noticed that you cross posted this exact same question on Stack Overflow - cross posting is not generally allowed on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: ok sorry for this issue. It is just that I didnt get any answer there so  I posted in the question here